# How to style to slideshow images

Tags: css

I created a carousel slideshow images using drupal bootstrap. Slideshow is working just fine. I added 3 images. Each image is about 1000x750. I would like to style these images so they look better in responsive devices. I like to see part of the images in slideshow even though original sizes are 1000x750. Below is the best I could explain as for what I am trying to do as I am bit confused.

When i visit the slideshow, images look big. When I make the screen responsive, images do not look right. I have not applied any css yet. I would like to apply css to the images so they look professional as I am making the screens responsive. I might be confusing you. So I shared a link.

If you visit this link, you will notice that original images are bigger than actual slide images. Also, slideshow images show only portion of the original images. Thats exactly what I would like to do.

[sample link](http://youselecthealthinsurance.com/)

My code.

```
<div class="view view-views-slideshow-home-page">

    <div class="view-content">
      <div id="views-bootstrap-carousel-1" class="views-bootstrap-carousel-plugin-style carousel slide">
      <!-- Carousel indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#views-bootstrap-carousel-1" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
              <li data-target="#views-bootstrap-carousel-1" data-slide-to="1" class="active"></li>
          </ol>

  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item">
        <img typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" src = "/sites/default/files/insu.jpg" width="1000" height="667" alt="">
      </div>
          <div class="item active">
        <img typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-responsive" src="/sites/default/files/ins.jpg" width="1000" height="667" alt="">
      </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Carousel navigation -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#views-bootstrap-carousel-1" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#views-bootstrap-carousel-1" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
    </div>


</div>
```

How can I apply css to the images and the wrapper so images look responsive and professional?

Comment: If you inspect the website you link, you'll notice that that images are set as a background with the following styles: 
`background-repeat: no-repeat`
`background-size: cover`
`background-position: top center`

Comment: I applied the code to the class "view-views-slideshow-home-page". No result.